# Beamer bug? Description with item width and overlay in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

This MWE is really minimal. We make use of the `{description}` environment which in `beamer` takes two optional arguments: overlay specification, and item width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{The Animal Kingdom}
        \begin{description}[<+->][Guans of America]
            \item[Gnus] these are large cow-like animals
            \item[Gnats] much smaller than gnus
            \item[Guans of America] mid sized, I think
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, this works great in beamer mode, but not in beamerarticle, which generates the following message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7         \item[Gnus] t
             hese are large cow-like animals
?
```

This seems like a bug, IMHO.  I wonder if there is a workaround that scales. I have few dozens instances of this problem in a large presentation.

---

Joseph Wright's fix to this bug in the beamer source can be found [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/aa881baf4ee217a8918166dc4f092381311b209f).

```
 {
    \AtBeginDocument{
      \let\beamer@origdescription=\description
 -    \renewcommand{\description}[1][]{\beamer@origdescription}
 +    % The description environment doesn't use either optional
 +    % arg in article mode, so simply gobble them
 +    \def\description{%
 +      \@ifnextchar[%]
 +        {\beamer@description@}
 +        {\beamer@origdescription}%
 +    }
 +    \def\beamer@description@[#1]{%
 +      \@ifnextchar[%]
 +        {\beamer@description@@}
 +        {\beamer@origdescription}%
 +    }
 +    \def\beamer@description@@[#1]{\beamer@origdescription}
    }
  }
```

I tried using this idea in an `\mode<article>` guard, but could not. Any help in finding a temporary work around until the release of the next version, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Agreed: definitely a big. Logged as https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/305/second-optional-arg-for-decscription-env, will investigate probably later today.

Comment: Thanks for resolving this issue. A workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll post a work-around in a bit (after work!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround: move the overlay specification to the `frame` environment. In the MWE example, write:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[<+->]{The Animal Kingdom}
        \begin{description}[Guans of America]
            \item[Gnus] these are large cow-like animals
            \item[Gnats] much smaller than gnus
            \item[Guans of America] mid sized, I think
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In frames with richer overlay specification, you would have to work around the default overlay specification.